# Can I use background Service to keep monitoring for iBeacon?

Tags: android, ibeacon, estimote

I try to create a `IntentService` to monitoring estimote beacon in background.
After I start the service on `Activity`, it throws error

`Service com.estimote.examples.demos.ScanBeaconService has leaked ServiceConnection com.estimote.sdk.BeaconManager$InternalServiceConnection@48523f80 that was originally bound here`

My ScanBeanService class:

```
public class ScanBeaconService extends IntentService {

    private BeaconManager beaconManager;

    int NOTIFICATION_ID = 111111; 

    NotificationManager notificationManager;

    private static final Region ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS_REGION = new Region("rid", null, null, null);

    public ScanBeaconService() {
        super("ScanBeaconService");
    }

    public ScanBeaconService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(getClass().getName(), "start service ScanBeaconService");
        com.estimote.sdk.utils.L.enableDebugLogging(true);  

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);
        if (!beaconManager.hasBluetooth()) {
            postNotification("don't have bt");
        } else if (!beaconManager.isBluetoothEnabled()) {
            postNotification("bt not enable");
        }

        beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceReady() {
                postNotification("beacon manager ready");
            }
        });


    beaconManager.setMonitoringListener(new MonitoringListener() {
          @Override
          public void onEnteredRegion(Region region, List<Beacon> beacons) {
            postNotification("Entered region");
          }

          @Override
          public void onExitedRegion(Region region) {
            postNotification("Exited region");
          }
        });
        try {
            beaconManager.startMonitoring(ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS_REGION);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Error while starting monitoring");
        }   
    }

    private void postNotification(String msg) {
        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, NotifyDemoActivity.class);
        notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(
            this,
            0,
            new Intent[]{notifyIntent},
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.beacon_gray)
        .setContentTitle("Notify Demo")
        .setContentText(msg)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .build();
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to do something continuously in the background, use Service not IntentService.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks for comment, I would try it